# Gzipping a CSV file truncates it

Tags: python, csv, gzip

I have a script that writes data to a CSV file and then gzips it.

The bizarre thing is the gzipped file is truncated by a few lines (total file size is over 18million lines).

I've manually gzipped the CSV file produced by the script and there is no file truncated. However, when I use Python to gzip the file (I've tried gzip, os, and subprocess), the file is truncated. I can't figure out why this might be happening.

Code snippet below:

```
#Remove quotes from file
with open(localFile, "r") as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, skipinitialspace=True)

    #Skip the header row
    next(csvreader)
    writer = csv.writer(open(outputFile, "w"), quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    for row in csvreader:
        writer.writerow(row)

#Zip file
zipCommand = f"gzip {outputFile}"
exit_code =os.system(zipCommand)
```

Comment: Try flushing the output file before running `gzip` on it.

Comment: Or better yet, use a `with open(outputFile, "w") as …` to do the writing, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*total file size is over 18million lines*

I assume that holding whole of this in RAM memory is not option. You might give [csv.writer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) [gzip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html)'s file handle to avoid that. Consider following simple example:

```
import csv, gzip
with gzip.open("file.csv.gz", "wt") as gf:
    writer = csv.writer(gf, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    writer.writerow([1,2,3])
    writer.writerow([4,5,6])
    writer.writerow([7,8,9])
```

this will create `file.csv.gz`, after `gunzip file.csv.gz` you will get file with following content

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

Note: use `wt` (write-text) mode for usage with `csv.writer` which emits text.